# How can I test if my ISP is throttling my connection to certain domains?

Tags: networking, internet

Is there a tool I can use that would definitively show whether or not certain domains are being throttled by my ISP? Maybe there's a script out there?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Glasnost test](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/glasnost.php). Unfortunately, there's no way to tell for sure 100%, but right now the Glasnost is the best thing out there to detect traffic throttling. Also, there are datum for different ISPs and other valuable resources.